# Which is the preferred usage?

Tags: grammar

Both side part right/part wrong to me; which one is preferred:

A)
Note, though, that Don Quixote's “olde” Spanish/English has been preserved in 
order to retain its intended comic effect

B)
Note, though, that Don Quixote's “olde” Spanish/English have been preserved in 
order to retain their intended comic effect

Comment: I think the version without the slash is preferred, at least in formal writing.

Comment: @PeterShor Both come with the slash!

Comment: @Kris: except that in this case, it's not clear whether the "/" really means "or" or "and".

Comment: @PeterShor The slash doesn't mean *and*.

Comment: @Kris: but it's not clear to me that "or" makes any sense in this sentence. Which is one reason why would be better to use a version without the slash, per my first comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version is the right one all right. The oblique stands for *or*, so the singular *its*. The second is incorrect.

> A) Note, though, that Don Quixote's “olde” Spanish/English has been preserved in order to retain its intended comic effect.

The language used in the Spanish (or English, as the case may be) **has** been preserved in order to retain **its** intended comic effect.

Comment: This is what I will use:
Note, though, that Don Quixote's “olde” Spanish (or English, as the case may be) has been preserved in order to retain its intended comic effect.

Comment: It is not adequate to assert 'the oblique stands for _or_'; the slash has other usages. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_(punctuation)): [An additional] use of the slash is to replace the hyphen or en dash to make a clear, strong joint between words or phrases, such as "the Hemingway/Faulkner generation". We need to see more context to be sure what meaning is intended, but the 'or' version seems illogical to me (I might be wrong). Certainly, in 'black/white films', the slash stands in for 'and'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No confusion. "'the Hemingway generation' (which some may want to call 'the Faulkner generation')" -- it doesn't mandate that Hemingway & Faulkner should both necessarily be addressed, as they are contemporaries -- one's generation is the other's as well. "Black/White films" is more appropriate than "Black & White films" -- the images are either black (on white) or white (on black) -- nothing can be both black and white at one time. It came to be so later in order to distinguish from color film. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_(punctuation)#In_English_text is clear enough.

Comment: The [Punctuation Guide](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/slash.html) advises some usages are best kept informal: The slash sometimes serves as shorthand for **and**, as in:
 
He is enrolling in the JD/MBA program at Harvard. . . . Conflict or connection
 
The slash is sometimes used to represent a **conflict** or **connection** between two things. . . .[T]he en dash can perform the same role.
 
Slash: The Paris/London train leaves in an hour.
En dash: The Paris–London train leaves in an hour.
 
Slash: This perfectly illustrates the nature/nurture debate.
En dash: . . . nature–nurture debate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I tried to drive home the point that the slashed pairs never occur simultaneously. Try. HTH.

Comment: I've tried: Black-and-white, often abbreviated B/W or B&W, is a term referring to a number of monochrome forms in visual arts.
Black-and-white images are not usually starkly contrasted black and white. They combine black and white in a continuum producing a range of shades of gray. [Wikipedia] You can have a black-and-white (B/W) image. Or a coloured one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "/" in this sentence plays the role of "or". So the sentence A should be sound since the author allegedly refers to either versions of the Don Quixote; English or Spanish.

Comment: The oblique or slash (/) is used to represent *or*, not *and*. Sometimes the context may imply *as the case may be*, yet only one of the alternatives applies.

Comment: Oh sorry, but I have seen that in both cases. Then I will edit it.

Comment: @Kris, are you using 'yet' in your comment to say '*but in any case*' or to say '*nevertheless*'?

Comment: @ElberichSchneider In the sense of 'even then' :)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I have seen "/" to mean a combination (otherwise depicted by ":" or "[endash]", as well as "and/or" or "and or or", or "'and' or 'or'". I think you need to use what is most likely to be understood as your intended meaning. Most people would see "/" as "and/or" or "or": if this is not clear from your context, then you should revise your punctuation choice. The choice of plural or singular agreement should follow.